# Mysql select multiple rows based on one row related date range

Tags: mysql

SQL structure

```
id, startdate, enddate  
1, 2012-01-01, 2012-10-01
```

I need sql statment to receive duplicate rows from startdate to enddate range.

Example result would be:

```
1, 2012-01-01
1, 2012-02-01
1, 2012-03-01
...
1, 2012-10-01
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this???

Comment: what do you need? Add some realistic data to example !!

Comment: Well I have events table where some events last multiple days. I need to get a record for every single day on which these events are taking place on along with events that last only one day.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this :

```
SELECT
  id, startdate, enddate
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  (startdate, enddate) IN 
  (
    SELECT
      startdate, enddate
    FROM
       myTable
    GROUP BY
      startdate, enddate
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 1     
  )
```